# curved line css rounded border

Tags: html, css

How can I get rounded borders at the top and bottom of this curved line. Checkout the white line of this picture, that is what I want to achieve with CSS. [Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVpon.png)

My Snippet:

```css
.curved-line {
  position: absolute;
  width: 180px;
  height: 90px;
  border: solid 12.5px #000;
  border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
  border-radius: 50%/100% 100% 0 0;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  margin-left: 45px;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="curved-line"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `:before` & `:after` pseudo elements.

```
.curved-line:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 95%;
  left: -12px;
  width: 12.5px;
  height: 12.5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: black;
}

.curved-line:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 95%;
  right: -11.5px;
  width: 12.5px;
  height: 12.5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: black;
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
.curved-line {
  position: absolute;
  width: 180px;
  height: 90px;
  border: solid 12.5px #000;
  border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
  border-radius: 50%/100% 100% 0 0;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  margin-left: 45px;
  margin-top: 60px;
  position: relative;
}

.curved-line:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 95%;
  left: -12px;
  width: 12.5px;
  height: 12.5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: black;
}

.curved-line:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 95%;
  right: -11.5px;
  width: 12.5px;
  height: 12.5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="curved-line"></div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, creative solution :)

Comment: Its my pleasure! @Fronteerder

Comment: This doesn't work for me but it does make a cute face :)  https://sharing.s3.wasabisys.com/VgBmlxR8eDkalxnY.png

Comment: @Andrew Look for the sizes (i.e. `width`, `height`, `top`, `bottom`, etc.). In your case, this might differ from mine. So, consider changing the values based on your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pseudoelements before and after the curved-line class.

```css
.curved-line {
  position: relative;
  width: 180px;
  height: 90px;
  border: solid 12.5px #000;
  border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
  border-radius: 50%/100% 100% 0 0;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.curved-line:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 99%;
  top: 91%;
  background-color: black;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.curved-line:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -7%;
  top: 91%;
  background-color: black;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="curved-line"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var c = document.getElementById("curvedLine");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(20, 20);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(20, 140, 170, 140, 170, 20);
ctx.lineWidth = 10; //width of the line
ctx.lineCap = 'round';
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="curvedLine"></canvas>
```

You can also use canvas to do this task

Comment: Good to know how to do that in JavaScript as well :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make the borders rounded using css pseudo class.

```css
.curved-line {
  position: absolute;
  width: 180px;
  height: 90px;
  border: solid 12px #000;
  border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
  border-radius: 50%/100% 100% 0 0;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  margin-left: 45px;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
 .curved-line:after{
  content: "";
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 86px;
  display: block;
 left: -11px;
}
 .curved-line:before{
  content: "";
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 86px;
  display: block;
 left: 179px;
}
```

```html
<div class="curved-line"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use befor and after , so you know use curved try to use 3 curved superimposed :)

```css
.curved-line {
  position: absolute;
  width: 180px;
  height: 100px;
/*   background: black; */
  border: solid 12.5px #000;
  border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
  border-radius: 50%/100% 100% 0 0;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  margin-left: 45px;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
.curved-line:before {
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  left: 115px;
/*   background: black; */
  border: solid 12.5px #000;
  border-color: white transparent transparent transparent;
  border-radius: 50%/100% 100% 0 0;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  margin-left: 45px;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
.curved-line:after {
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  left: -74px;
/*   background: black; */
  border: solid 12.5px #000;
  border-color: white transparent transparent transparent;
  border-radius: 50%/100% 100% 0 0;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  margin-left: 45px;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="curved-line"></div>
```